# Getting container resource metrics from kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I am exploring client-go library for collecting resource metric for a kubernetes cluster. I am more keen on collecting the container metrics from all the pods.

But according to the wiki, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/, i see that we can only get pod or node level metrics and not container level metrics.

Is there a way i can collect container level metric (like the way docker api gives the metrics for a container)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deploy the External Metric server like Prometheus Adapter (example of full metric solution mentioned in official doc you linked).
The quickest way to achieve it is via [kube-prometheus](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/contrib/kube-prometheus#quickstart) repository, which is part of [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator) project.
It already includes kube-state-metrics, which generates custom metrics of your interest ([Pod Metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md)), example of container related one: kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores.

Comment: Thanks! Does metrics-server not give the container metrics?